# Trouble with string alignment when adding strings on a listbox

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm pulling data from an API and concatenating it into a string that I'm formatting in every iteration.

Here is the piece of code where I format a string and add it to the listbox:

```
rezultat = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", stevilka.PadRight(7), smer.PadRight(25), prihodi);
rezultati.Items.Add(rezultat);
```

Where `rezultati` is the name of the listbox and `stevilka, smer, prihodi` are the columns I am trying to align in a listbox. The current output looks like this:

[image: output]

I'm using a mono-font (courier new) but I guess there is something else I'm missing out?

Comment: That font doesn't look like courier new to be honest

Comment: @rene I have this under ListBox properties: FontFamily="Courier New", so It should be Courier New?

Comment: Well it should but as one can plainly see it isn't.

Comment: @TaW any reason why that could be happening?

Comment: No. A few ideas: Put a breakpoint to see what the currently assigned Font is. Also search for any spot where you do a Font assignment. I assume that the Font is available? Try using Consolas.

Comment: @TaW I've added break points and checked what the Font Family is and it's Courier New everytime, but the output still seems to be the default font and I have no idea why.. Tried Consolas, same thing..

Comment: I don't do UPW. so I don't know what else to do; maybe add a Button, that explcitly sets the font and see if that change works.. It must be something else than, say, a fixed vs proportional property. Courier is a Serif font that has a very characteristic typewriter look!

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar to the UWP platform, but if you would populate a `ListBox` in WPF like you did, `string.Format"{0} {1} {2}"` alone does in no way guarantee that each item and its columns are aligned to one another.

I think there aren't any controls that implement the "column behavior" per default, but maybe you should have a look at the `GridView` or `ListView` controls.

[Guidelines for list view and grid view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465465.aspx)